# insert two different column data type data into one column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table called `employee`.  It contains:

- employee_id (INTEGER)
- date_of_joining (DATE)
- salary (INTEGER)

Now I want to insert record in employee table like salary is replaced by `salary + date_of_joining`; see the last column is changed ( `salary + date_of_joining` )

[image]

Comment: I have a table called employee.
It contains employee_id,date_of_joining,salary.
data type => employee_id = integer
date_of_joining = date 
salary = integer;

Comment: I have a table called employee.
It contains employee_id,date_of_joining,salary.
data type => employee_id = integer
date_of_joining = date 
salary = integer;

Now i want to insert record in employee table  like salary is replaced by salary+date_of_joining;

see the last column is changed ( salary+date_of_joining )

Comment: make your salary column to data type String and parse salary+date_of_joining to string before save the data.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do.  Do you want to add a new row with the value of salary = `salary + date_of_joining`?  `salary` is an `INTEGER` so you'd have to convert `date_of_joining` to an `INTEGER` first.

Comment: I want to change salary value as salary+date of joining

Comment: insert into employee(new_column_created) select cast(salary as varchar2(100) )||cast (date_of_joining as varchar2(100) ) as a 
from backup_table where 1=1;  this query runs successfully but when run select * from employee ; then new_column_created value is blank ? hows?

Comment: finally Done.

create table employee_backup as select * from employee;
delete from employee;
alter table employee modify salary varchar2(200);
insert into employee(employee_id,date_of_joining,salary) 
select employee_id,date_of_joining,cast(date_of_joining as varchar2(100)) ||', '||cast (salary as varchar2(100)) as result ,
from employee_backup where 1=1;

Comment: @shubham update the *question* and explain what you want. Adding a date and decimal makes no sense - what would the result be? A date? Or a decimal? *Creating a string* from those two values is a different story.

Answer (score 1):

The computed column is an answer.
Leave the current column as it is, just define a new one to be computed.

*A computed column is a virtual column that is not physically stored in the table, unless the column is marked PERSISTED. A computed column expression can use data from other columns to calculate a value for the column to which it belongs. You can specify an expression for a computed column in SQL Server 2017 by using SQL Server Management Studio or Transact-SQL.*

[Specify Computed Columns in a Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Yes but now i want that virtual column as a perment column then what shoult i do

Comment: Computed columns used as CHECK, FOREIGN KEY, or NOT NULL constraints must be marked PERSISTED.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms191250(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN